# How to create custom route by dragging marker in android Google MapV2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am in need to create custom route in android Google mapV2.

As describe in the Image given below.

[image]

As of now i am able to get the route between two latlng by json request, but didn't find any way to modify it.

Comment: @AG What do you want? don't get it.

Comment: I want to create a route between two lat long and also want to modify the route by dragging points on map as you can see in the image

Comment: @AG see my answer if u have any doubts let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this way: first set `options.draggable(true);`  to your add `Marker` like

```
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);
            options.draggable(true);

            if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                options.title("Marker1");
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                options.title("Marker2");
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            map.addMarker(options);
```

And now, implement `setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener(){...}` into your `Activity` like:

```
 map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             LatLng dragPosition = marker.getPosition();
              double dragLat = dragPosition.latitude;
              double dragLong = dragPosition.longitude;

        Toast.makeText(Main3.this, "After onMarkerDragEnd position: "+ dragLat+"  "+dragLong,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

In the `onMarkerDragEnd(....)` you can identify a `Marker` by it's title and Draw route Again between the New point and Older point.

Answer (score 1):

At present this functionality is not available for android in API V2. You can do this in website for browser using API V3. In Android when you try to get route between two Lat Long, you will need to call web service. Likewise you will need to call web service for each such route, which is not an efficient way. This will reduce performance of your application.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the navigation route half way in Google map application on a Desk Top.Place the arrow over the junction where the turn is required click and drag the white circle along the new route you want until it joins the earlier as a diversion. The new route is created.

A highlighted request appears on the left - " Do you want this sent to your phone?" Click it and select Email. The map is sent to your Android phone Email. Open it . The map is there and it is navigable!!